# Create a fixed collapsable accordion at bottom of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a fixed collapsable accordion at the bottom of the page window like this [sample](https://pixelarity.com/landscape). in the sample we have the grey accordion at the bottom.

Any help will be great.

Thanks.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

```css
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the accordion panel when the user clicks on one of the buttons. This will show the panel content */
div.panel.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper `div` and give it the following `style`:

```
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Only the animation is missing, but not sure if you want to have that.

**DEMO**

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  widtH: 100%;
}
/* Style the buttons that are used to open and close the accordion panel */

button.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */

div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}
/* The "show" class is added to the accordion panel when the user clicks on one of the buttons. This will show the panel content */

div.panel.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```