# MUI Accordion at the bottom of the window

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I'm looking for an material react expandable that stays on footer and opens when clicked from bottom to top.

All the material accordions / collapsible expand from top to bottom which make the page grow. Example : https://materializecss.com/collapsible.html

I was able to find [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39769899/7275579) using HTML and JS, but looking for out of box react / material components.

Comment: So basically you want an `Accordion` that is placed at the bottom with body on top?

Comment: Partly yes, but I wanted the accordion header also to move up when clicked leaving the content down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want the [`Accordion`](https://mui.com/components/accordion/#main-content) component. To make it stick at the bottom, set the position to `fixed` and bottom to `0`.

```
<Accordion
  sx={{
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: 0,
  }}
>
  <AccordionSummary>
    {...}
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>
    {...}
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, but this is partly my expectation. In the sandbox, the header still stays at bottom, in the example stack overflow link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39769899/7275579), the header moves up.

Comment: @Aswath see my updated answer, I probably misread your question.

Comment: Now it meets my intended output, thanks a lot for patiently resolving this